# Why is the funnel visualization in Google Analytics broken?

Tags: magento, google-analytics

I have an eCommerce store in Magento (if that matters). I have a goal setup as "Buy tickets", Goal type as "Destination, and here is the setup:

[image: Google Analytics Goal Setup]

The funnel seems to be "broken", as obviously doesn't seem to be working right. I'm not the most advanced user, and still learning, so not sure what the problem is! Hope someone can help, thank you.

[image: Google Analytics Goal Funnel]

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression for Step 2 also matches Step 3 and 4. This causes inaccuracies.

Try the below for your regex pattern instead. Unfortunately Google Analytics doesn't support negative lookaheads in regular expressions - so this is more convoluted than it should be.

**Step 2**: `/checkout/[A-Za-z0-9\-\.]+`

This assumes the only special characters that could appear in your URL are `-` and `.`. Modify to add more if needed (except for `#`).

Answer (score 0):

Replace Step 1 with Regex to allow all formats of homepage

`^/$|^/\?`